# delete element from non-associatve array

Tags: php, arrays

**Suppose I have the following array. How can I delete the word "are"**
(the index can be random so doing `unset($words[2])` is not an option)

```
$words= array("hi", "how", "are", "you", "doing");
//array_remove("are", $words); <== How to do this in php?
```

Comment: So, you've made no attempts at this or..?

Comment: I think we need more explanation about how the index could be random

Comment: Do you need to maintain consecutive ordering? Perhaps a more complete example would have been useful.

Comment: You can find an index for a given value, then remove by the index ..

Comment: @AlexW random as in. I am loading user generated text from a db and I want to be able to remove a certain word. In this canse I wont know what index the word is at that I want to remove. What I have above is a simple example to simplify what I want

Comment: @symcbean No, I don't need to maintain ordering or anything as such.

Comment: @user2246674 yes I can, but I was just curious if there is a function already. I tried googleing but mostly people used associative arrays so was left with no choice but to ask here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search):

```
function array_remove($word, &$array) 
{
    if (($key = array_search('are', $array)) !== false) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$words = array("hi", "how", "are", "you", "doing");
array_remove('are', $words);
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/ZAGmyIhM)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search) to find the index and remove it using unset

```
if (($index = array_search('are', $words)) !== false) {
unset($words[$index]);
}
```

`array_search` returns false if no item has been found.

And if you want to remove multiple instances of "are" you can try [array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys)

```
foreach(array_keys($words,"are") as $index) {
unset($words[$index])
}
```

Although this will make the element with value "are" simply disappear.So in your example, your array will no longer contain the index 2. This might cause problem for loops that work on index iteration. To remvoe this you can use [array_values](https://www.php.net/array_values)

```
$words = array_values($words);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function for it, this does exactly what your comment describes:

```
function array_remove($needle, & $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === $needle) {
            unset($haystack[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
$words= array("hi", "how", "are", "you", "doing");
array_remove('are', $words);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($words);
```

If you want the function to remove all instances of the `$needle` then just remove the line that says `break;`.